# Compare 2 DateTime values in a WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server

I have a very simple query.  (I'm working in SQL Server 2008.)  I'm trying to select all records from a view where their ModifiedOn column is greater than a specified date.  The ModifiedOn column is a datetime format.  So, I have:

```
DECLARE @date1 AS datetime = '2013-07-31 24.59.59.999'
SELECT
some_column
FROM dbo.some_view
WHERE ModifiedOn > @date1
```

SQL is throwing the following error, though:
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.  Why is SQL thinking that one of my dates is a varchar, when I know that both of them are datetime formats?  How do I fix it?

Comment: It should be  `@date1 AS datetime = '2013-07-31 23:59:59.999'` and not `'2013-07-31 24.59.59.999'`

Comment: You could make it easier on yourself and defined the datetime as '2013-08-01' and change your where predicate to >= @date1

Comment: Honestly, it would be simpler, and probably easier to read, if you used `'2013-08-01'` and change your operator from `>` to `>=`. The datetime will default to midnight of the date specified if you don't provide a time.

Comment: @M.Ali in addition to the colons the hour is set to 24 which is not valid.

Comment: Yep, the 24 is a problem.   This works for me:  SELECT CAST('20130731 23:59:59.999' AS datetime)

Comment: Stop trying to find the end of the day - this doesn't work. Use M.Ali's answer and read these: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx

Comment: Reading these blogs taught me a lot thank you @AaronBertrand for writing these :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datetime variable expects data to be in format of

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.mmm
```

In your case you are trying to assign a value which is not a valid time. `HH.MM.SS.mmm`

Secondly a clock never strikes `24:00:00` it goes from  `23:59:59.999` to `00:00:00.001`.

Also in your case rather than juggling with seconds and milliseconds. just use date value and use the ANSI standard `YYYYMMDD` which is also sargable.

You could have written your above query something like

```
SELECT some_column
FROM dbo.some_view
WHERE ModifiedOn >= '20130801'
```